# Hello Android application not working

Tags: android

Today I have started with setting up of Android Development Environment using Eclipse for java developers, Android SDK and ADT Plugin on Windows 7 exactly following the steps given on http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html but I'm stuck in between. I have written HelloAndroid application in same way as described on this link but when I'm running this code then it is not working. Following errors are shown in red:-

```
[2011-07-11 23:25:36 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: Files.
[2011-07-11 23:25:36 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-07-11 23:25:36 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a new bug. You have to install your android sdk to a path that doesn't contain spaces. So c:\program files\android would fail, try c:\android.

Alternatively, you could first run your emulator by browsing to your androidsdk\tools folder, and open a command prompt there. Then use

> emulator @foo

where foo is your avd name.

(You can also ofcourse, if you have one, deploy the application on your android phone, generally faster and easier to use)

Comment: I adopted alternative method,Now it is working but window size is very large.Is there anything which I can do to make it normal?

Comment: @mukul: The easy workaround is to change your AVD resolution to HVGA or QVGA, which are both smaller than the WVGA/WQVGA resolutions. The window size should become smaller.

Comment: @Niek: another workaround is to set the sdk path in Eclipse to C:\PROGRA~1\...\android-sdk-windows (or \PROGRA~2 if it was put in Program Files (x86))

Comment: @GiantMarshmallow:Thanx for the help.It really worked and I also implemented your idea of setting the path as C:\PROGRA~2\...It's working fine now.Can you do me one more favour?Please tell me some good sites to learn programming Android Application.Actually I have been working on a project to develop Android Dictionary,so it'll be a great help for me.

Comment: Personally, I used Marko Gargenta's [Learning Android](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920010883), which I think is a great book for getting started and learning a bit about each of the major parts of the Android SDK. It appears that you can read this online [for free](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449390501/), though I went ahead and purchased it.